# List out all "Layout Tabs" in the frontend

Tags: field-layout-designer

[image]

I have a few tabs in my "Field Layout Design", and I wondered if there was a way to list the titles of each one, in the frontend? Something basic like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Testimonials</li>
  <li>Gallery</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have an 'entry', this should work:

```
{% for tab in entry.getFieldLayout().getTabs() %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ tab.name }}
            <ul>
                {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
                    <li>{{ field.name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

if you don't need the fields then just:

```
{% for tab in entry.getFieldLayout.getTabs() %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ tab.name }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Exactly what I was after. Thank you Douglas :)

Comment: How to get the value of a field of tabs?

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald For example in the tab "gallery" is the field of "image", how to get it? `entry.image` nothing gives, only if "image" was in the first tab

Comment: @VitaliyBadalov I don't understand your question? What do you mean by a "value of a field of tabs"? Do you mean "value of a field within the tabs"? In the future it might be best to create a new question (with a link to this question).

Comment: I'll be glad to help, but can you start a new question please. It's hard to give a good answer within comments.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Sorry, i just forgot to put in the field to tab in "Field Layout Design"

Comment: @VitaliyBadalov OK. Glad you found an answer!