# Get selected values from all of an entry’s Multi-select fields

Tags: templating

I am new in Craft, and will be happy if I can get help with this task. I have a tab that contains only multiselect fields. What I want to do, is to get all selected values for all multiselects field in this tab. I find this [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/5253/4109) to get all field from a tab, but I can't get the selected values for the entry. Here is my code:

```
{% for tab in entry.getFieldLayout().getTabs() %}
  {% if tab.name == 'Spec' %}
    <ul>
      <li>{{ tab.name }}
        <ul>
          {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
            <li>{{ field.getField().name }}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all of the selected values of a multi-select field like this:

```html
{% for value in entry.myFieldHandle %}
  <li>{{ value }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

(See the [Multi-select field docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-select-fields#templating) for other examples.)

The easiest way to loop through *all* of your multi-select fields’ values would be to manually merge all of their values into a new array:

```html
{% set values = entry.fieldHandleOne
    |merge([entry.fieldHandleTwo])
    |merge([entry.fieldHandleThree]) %}

{% for value in values %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you really don’t want to hardcode the field handles in your template, then you can go the getFieldLayout() route. That `field.getField()` function will give you the actual [FieldModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/FieldModel) that represents the field. You can use its `handle` property to access the field’s selected values on your `entry`:

```html
{% set values = [] %}

{% for tab in entry.getFieldLayout().getTabs() %}
  {% if tab.name == 'Spec' %}
    {% for field in tab.getFields() %}
      {% set handle = field.getField().handle %}
      {% set fieldValues = entry.getFieldValue(handle) %}
      {% set values = values|merge([fieldValues]) %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for value in values %}
  {% for selected in value %}
    <li>{{ selected}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I have been trying your solution, but I get this error `The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes; array and object given.`.

Comment: I made a quick search and solve the problem adding square brackets `{% set values = values|merge([fieldValues]) %}` and another loop to print the values `{% for value in values %} {% for selected in value %}  <li>{{ selected }}</li>
{% endfor %} {% endfor %}`. If There is a better solution I will be glad to know it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @IvayloPetrov Whoops, sorry about that! Just fixed the code.

Comment: Don`t worry, we all are humans ;) You miss to fix last code example :) I fixed it :)